# What's the most readable way to turn a pattern match into an Option?

Tags: rust

When dealing with complex structures with nested enums, I often find myself writing ancillary methods for selecting a specific branch:

```rust
impl MyEnum {
    fn as_foo(&self) -> Option<&Foo> {
        if let Self::Foo(foo) = self { Some(foo) } else { None }
    }
}
```

Which are quite convenient to chain using the `?` operator. They can also be used transparently trough boxes and other smart pointers, which is not the case of nested patterns (at least until RFC2099/MCP77 becomes a thing?).

Unfortunately, the syntax here is quite redundant and cumbersome. How can this be done better?

I can use something like the following macro:

```
macro_rules! some_match {
    ($p:pat = $e:expr => $r:expr) => { if let $p = $e { Some($r) } else { None } }
}
```

```
fn as_foo(&self) -> Option<&Foo> {
    some_match!(MyEnum::Foo(p) = self => p)
}
```

but I would prefer a solution coming from the standard library, which would be less surprising to the reader.

Comment: rust-analyzer has an assist for that: https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#generate_enum_as_method

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes but I'm worried about the readability, not the writability.

Comment: In my experience, those are small enough to be trivially readable. And you can split them into a new `impl` block too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any `std` solution, but there are various crates that may help you:

- Possibly closest to what you want: https://docs.rs/variantly/0.2.0/variantly/index.html
- https://docs.rs/enum-methods/latest/enum_methods/

Comment: Great. Looks pretty much like what I would have attempted to write on my own. But the low number of downloads on crates.io worries me a bit; could be a bit too exotic?